# Is it possible to increase the size of RAM of a CISCO UCS blade server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, cisco, memory, cisco-ucs

We have a Cisco UCS Server which has 256GB RAM and installed with Win 2008 Server 64bit. I wanted to know can we upgrade its RAM to 512GB RAM? Is it possible to do that or do we need to build a new server with OS with 512GB RAM from scratch?

Thanks

Comment: Ask Cisco, it's their appliance...

Comment: In general is it possible to increase the RAM of a physical server?

Comment: Of course. But it depends on how much memory it has and how much it can hold, and also on how its memory banks are currently filled. Last but not least, this is not a *server*, this is an *appliance*: even if you *could* increase its RAM, tinkering with it could very well void its warranty and/or its support. Just do yourself a favour and ask the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

The OP specified "blade server", which is not an appliance.  The fabric interconnects could be considered appliances, but only in the way any network gear is an appliance.  Not in the newer use such as "firewall appliance", or "log collection appliance".

As already noted, the Cisco UCS blade servers can be upgraded like any other vendor's server.  It depends on the model.  Cisco's web site has the spec sheets that will tell you what your server can do.  If you need help contact the vendor you bought the gear from.  Installing Cisco approved RAM on your own won't void any warranty.  We do most of our own hardware work out of convenience and let Cisco support send in techs for annoying things like replacing motherboards.